# SQL Server : extract differences between values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a query. I have a table with 2 columns `dates` and `values`.

I would like to extract a single row with the differences between the values
e.g. (value_day1 - value_day0), (value_day2 - value_day1), (value_day3 - value_day2) .... for each day of the month.

It's quite easy to have all the values I need, but I have 1 row per each day and that's not what I need.

```
declare @data date
declare @pdr varchar(14) /*an ID */

set @data = '20200201'
set @pdr = '03060000152746'

select @data, codicepdr, valorelettura, datalettura
from Tab_TelLettureGG 
inner join Tab_PuntiDiRiconsegna tab_pdr on tab_pdr.id = Tab_TelLettureGG.idpdr
where codicepdr = @pdr
  and month(Tab_TelLettureGG.datalettura) = month(@data)
  and year(Tab_TelLettureGG.datalettura) = year(@data) /* I need the values of that month */
order by DataLettura desc
```

Can anybody help me please ?

EDIT:
It's only one table with two columns

- column A (dates) column B (values)
- 1/1/2000     100
- 1/2/2000     110
- 1/3/2000     111
- 1/4/2000     120
- ...
- ...
- 1/30/2000    150
- 1/31/2000    200

I'd like to select in some way in a single row of 31 columns (always, even for february)

- 10 (110-100),1 (111-110), 9 (120-111) ..... 50 (200-150)

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include the current data format you are getting back and then adding an example of what that same data should look like? It will help give a more specific answer to your question.

Comment: What you want is called a pivot (look it up). In most cases, running a "regular" query and handling the pivoting in the presentation layer is actually better.

Comment: @giorgiga can you explain a little bit more about the pivot table please?